# How can i clean pouchdb when electron app is closing

Tags: javascript, electron, pouchdb

I have some PouchDBs in my electron app, and i need to clear some of these dbs when the app is closing or make these dbs only for that session!

I have currently 3 dbs: auth (i dont want to clear this one), home and page.
I want to keep the db while the app is running because it improves loading time, but when a new instance of the app is open i want these last 2 to be with no data.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why use pouchdb if you want data to be cleared?

Comment: The data needs to be cleared only if the app is closed, otherwise i still need the data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In-Memory adapter for PouchDB maybe?](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pouchdb-adapter-memory)

Or another idea: Create a random string when the app starts, create the PouchDB database with the string as suffix, for example `home-MjlhOGFlYmEy`, dump the data in there. A new instance of the app will use a different suffix and has a separate database. This, of course, doesn't clean old data. You could then think of strategies how to clean the old data, for example by keeping a list of all suffixes and have some garbage collector running that cleans old databases that are not in use anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I will try both of them and see whice one works better!